# PySimpleGUI table individual columns text align

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am looking at this sample code (from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pysimplegui/pysimplegui_table_element.htm). I haven't been able to find a working solution with a PySimpleGUI Table to have the first column (S.No.) align text to the left (and rest of columns text align centre).  Could someone please tell me if this is possible?  Thanks

```
import PySimpleGUI as psg
psg.set_options(font=("Arial Bold", 14))
toprow = ['S.No.', 'Name', 'Age', 'Marks']
rows = [[1, 'Rajeev', 23, 78],
        [2, 'Rajani', 21, 66],
        [3, 'Rahul', 22, 60],
        [4, 'Robin', 20, 75]]
tbl1 = psg.Table(values=rows, headings=toprow,
   auto_size_columns=True,
   display_row_numbers=False,
   justification='center', key='-TABLE-',
   selected_row_colors='red on yellow',
   enable_events=True,
   expand_x=True,
   expand_y=True,
 enable_click_events=True)
layout = [[tbl1]]
window = psg.Window("Table Demo", layout, size=(715, 200), resizable=True)
while True:
   event, values = window.read()
   print("event:", event, "values:", values)
   if event == psg.WIN_CLOSED:
      break
   if '+CLICKED+' in event:
      psg.popup("You clicked row:{} Column: {}".format(event[2][0], event[2][1]))
window.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 4.61.0.21
>
> Added cols_justification for Table element - list or tuple of strings that indicates how each column should be justified

You can change the option `justification` to `cols_justification`, like

```py
# New option for sg.Table
cols_justification="lccc",    # `l` for `left` and `c` for `center`.
```

Not all enhancements added into the PyPI version.
[Download from GitHub](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/#upgrading-from-github-using-pysimplegui)

> There is code in the PySimpleGUI package that upgrades your previously pip installed package to the latest version checked into GitHub.
> You can use the commands `psgmain` to run the test harness or `psgupgrade` to invoke the GitHub upgrade code.

or, you can call `sg.main()`, like

```py
d:\>python
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PySimpleGUI as sg
>>> sg.main()
```

[image: ![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/55352169/196456098-38004184-4538-453f-b163-e7e0151ec56b.png)]